# Conan2 & compiler sanitizers

Tags: c++, conan, address-sanitizer, conan-2, conanfile

How to use compiler sanitizers, especially the address sanitizer in Conan2? Searching on Google, the only result found is for version 1, which does not work on 2. I tried the profile below, but without success.

```
include(default)

[settings]
arch=wasm
os=Emscripten

compiler.sanitizer=Address

[tool_requires]
*: emsdk/3.1.44

[env]
CFLAGS=-fsanitize=address
CXXFLAGS=-fsanitize=address
LDFLAGS=-fsanitize=address
```

And:

```
[compiler_flags]
sanitizer=Address
```

Conan says that env or compiler_flags is not a recognized section.

Comment: *which does not work ... without success ... No luck* - How do you diagnose that?

Comment: @273K no work at all, I get a error saying that env does is not recognized

Comment: conan2 configuration file now is YAML, see https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/settings.html

Comment: @273K where is the sanitizers? they are supported?

Comment: Those settings are not standard, they have to be added to your own ``settings.yml`` file. For support-like discussions, better use the project Github: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add custom flags to compiler and linker in conan v2:

```
include(default)

[settings]
arch=wasm
os=Emscripten

[tool_requires]
*: emsdk/3.1.44

[conf]
tools.build:cflags=["-fsanitize=address"]
tools.build:cxxflags=["-fsanitize=address"]
tools.build:exelinkflags=["-fsanitize=address"]
tools.build:sharedlinkflags=["-fsanitize=address"]
```

If you want that these flags contribute to package id, add this to `~/.conan2/global.conf`:

```
tools.info.package_id:confs=["tools.build:cflags", "tools.build:cxxflags", "tools.build:exelinkflags", "tools.build:sharedlinkflags"]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: I've edited message, there was a typo in conf names (`:` instead of `.` before cflags etc)